# Do I need to uninstall apache httpd before installing tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, yum

I did `sudo yum groupinstall -y "Web Server" "PHP Support"`, on my ec2 instance. Now I want to install `apache tomcat`. Do I need to uninstall `httd` that was installed as a part of `yum groupinstall -y "Web Server"` ? If yes, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I never done it myself: no you don't have to uninstall httpd. I've seen them running next to eachother in the past. You do need to change the configuration of course since both can't listen to default port 80. :)